# forkJoin HTTP requests and merge responses in an array

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have read a lot of answers here, but it looks that I am not able to make it work.

I have an array of data that I want to iterate on it and call for each item, an HTTP service. Then join the results in one array.

The HTTP request returns an object like this one:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "data": {"seriesData": <array_of_objects>},
   "other": other data
}
```

What I want is to merge the `data['seriesData']` of all the responses.

```
let responses: Array<Observable<any>> = [];

for ( let country of this.selectedCountries ) {
    let response: Observable<any> = this.myApi.getChartData(country);
    responses.push(response);
}

Observable.forkJoin(responses)
   .map( response => response.reduce((a,b) => { return _.merge(a.data.seriesData, b.data.seriesData)}) )
   .subscribe( res => {            
        this.myData = res;
  });
```

However, I get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'seriesData' of undefined`

Answer (score 2):

This is because `_.merge(a.data.seriesData, b.data.seriesData)` will return object without `.data.seriesData` in it.

Also, I suggest you to write your logic like a series of transformations instead of `for of` + `reduce`. This way you will have more control over it and this should consume less memory because will gather result gradually

```js
// just to emulate request
const getFakeData = (country) => {
  return Rx.Observable
    .of({
      id: Date.now(),
      data: { 
        "seriesData": Array.from({ length: 10 })
          .map((_, index) => country + '-' + index),
        "other": 'other data'
      }
    })
    .delay(1000);
};

Rx.Observable
  .from(['en', 'de', 'uk', 'fr'])
  // mergeMap will do request in parralel, concatMap - successively
  .mergeMap(country => getFakeData(country))
  .reduce((acc, v) => acc.concat(v.data.seriesData), [])
  .subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I posted a similar answer, and deleted when I realized the similarity. Your answer is actually better.

Comment: I have this error with the above code: `Property 'concat' does not exist on type '{}'.`

Comment: Have you typed `[]` (empty array) as the last parameter of reduce?